# How to caculate power analysis in a descriptive study

Tags: anova, survey, likert, statistical-power, descriptive-statistics

Hi I'm currently doing a dissertation, its a descriptive quantitative study. The method of data collection is a questionnaire scaled by a 10 point Likert scale.

To calculate the sample population needed, I have been looking into power analysis. I have found information on estimating the single mean or proportion. However within my study I have 2 questionnaires, one with 15 questions and the other with 30. How do I go about calculating this, or am I looking at the wrong statistical test.

Comment: If this is descriptive, why bother with sample size and power analysis at all? Anyway, if you want to define the number of subjects needed, N, to estimate a single mean with a predefined margin of error, you probably want to retain the higher number of subjects depending on the value of N with your 15 or 30-item questionnaire. You will have to provide an estimate for the standard deviation as well.

Answer (score 1):

If your study is truly descriptive, you wouldn't be concerned with power analysis since you won't be doing statistical tests. You may be more concerned with the generalizability of the findings, which isn't assessed through the classical hypothesis tests that power analysis informs.

If you expect to be doing statistical tests, then you should consider power analysis prior to data collection. Statistical hypothesis tests focus on Type I errors: the probability of mistakenly finding something when there is nothing there. Power analysis focuses on Type II errors: the probability of missing something when it is there. If $\beta$ is the probability of a Type II error, Power is measured as $1-\beta$. Without getting too complicated with the math, the classic power formula identifies either:
- the sample size you need at a given power level and to identify an effect at a specified size
- the expected power you will obtain with a given sample size and the specified effect size
- the minimally detectable effect size you can identify with a given sample size at a given power level

The number of questions on your surveys, and the number of surveys you have, doesn't influence the power analysis directly. Rather, you need to think about the types of survey items you have (which it looks like you have done), think about the general size of the sampling frame, and expected response rates. To do conduct the power analysis, you need to know what statistical test you will be doing. For most basic statistical tests like these power is derived based on formulas. These can be calculated in pretty much any basic statistical package, like SPSS, R, Stata, SAS, etc. There are even specialized software for it (e.g [GPower](http://gpower.hhu.de/) which is free and pretty good) and Web sites that will calculate power. For complex tests, such as those used in multi-level or hierarchical models, simulation techniques are necessary.

When looking at power analysis results, we often want to create ranges of sample sizes, power, and effect size, rather than a single point. The idea many analysts take is to look for the minimally detectable effect size given a desired power level, and sample size. Some researchers will tell you that if you can't identify a reasonable effect size based on what you think the sample size will be (since cost usually goes up as sample goes up), it may not be worth doing the research at all. In your case, obviously, that probably isn't an option.

Take a look at the manual to GPower: http://gpower.hhu.de/, and the classic work from Cohen: http://books.google.com/books?id=2v9zDAsLvA0C. Cohen also talks about effect sizes, which is another topic you may be interested.